# Hover state not being activated when user hovers over link in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

We created this page: http://www.sandiego.edu/mysandiego/usd_portal/

On that page, there is a navigation bar.

```
<nav class="alignLeft">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Torero Hub</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="#">Welcome</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">My Academics</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">My Financial Aid</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">My Student Account</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">My Torero Services</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">My Gadgets</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Library</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Law Library</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Torero Life</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Student Affairs</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Clubs and Activities</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Graduate Life</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Alumni</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

The CSS should start like this:

```
.navBar nav li ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    left: 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

If you hover over the tab, it should pop up a secondary navigation menu. It does this by detecting the hover state and changing display: none to display: block.

```
.no-touch .navBar nav li:hover ul, .no-js .navBar nav li:hover ul, .navBar nav li ul.active {
    display: block;
}
```

This works for me on every browser and OS I've tested, but one user cannot get it to work in Chrome and Firefox and I really don't know why. It works for him in Internet Explorer.

When the user hovers over the tab in Chrome or Firefox, nothing happens. The user can only get the pop up to show up by clicking the tab, but never by just hovering.

User is using Windows 7 64-bit SP1 and Chrome Version 40.0.2214.85 beta-m (64-bit).

I asked other Windows 7 users to test with Chrome and Firefox and this works for them. What are we missing? Even if we right-click the nav bar element in the Element inspector and force the state to :hover state, this user is not seeing the hover CSS. What gives?

Edit: I found another user with the same issue, so it doesn't look isolated to a user's workstation. Both users are Windows 7 users and both can see the menu fine in Internet Explorer but not on Chrome or Firefox.

Edit 2: 
Changing the CSS from this

```
.no-touch .navBar nav li:hover ul,
.no-js .navBar nav li:hover ul,
.navBar nav li ul.active {
    display: block;
}
```

to this

```
.navBar nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

fixed the issue for all users. However, the same users with issues cannot click any links in the menu. If they right-click > Open Link in new tab, it works fine for them.

Comment: Maybe you should include some relevant code.

Comment: if it is 1 user then this isn't a problem for SO. you need to ask them to hard refresh their screen, restart their computer, and potentially look for reasons that their specific machine might be messing up.

Comment: @slime Sorry, I was still editing. It's up now.

Comment: @CayceK At this point, I suspect it may be an issue with Windows 7 64-bit users so I haven't been able to determine it's just an issue with one user. I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: I do not have beta so i can't be for sure, but I have 7 64bit and no issues here...

Comment: downloaded beta no issues.

Comment: @CayceK I think you may be correct in that this may not be a problem for SO. I'm asking other Windows 7 users to test and if I can't reproduce it I will delete the post.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. Given your current HTML and CSS, the nested ULs are not even hidden so what is there to even expand? And this would never be an OS issue when it's clearly a CSS one.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it properly...

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li class="more">more</li>
    <ul>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul ul {
    display: none;}

.more:hover + ul {
    display: block;}
```

What you need to make note of, is the use of `+` in the selector. Anything after your hover state will need this so it knows the immediate siblings need to be affected.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it. Why would it work properly in the same browsers for some users but not others, though? Even above @CayceK commented that using the same browser the navigation worked for him/her. Just trying to understand.

Comment: I can't comment on why it worked for some and not others, and I'm assuming they are referring to the link you provided. I was only working with the HTML/CSS you have included in your post and that's when I saw things were all wonky. Btw, the link you provided does work for me as well. But if the CSS you provided is being used then I would suggest reexamining it.

Comment: You were right. It was the CSS. I changed it and it now seems to work for everybody. However, now those affected users cannot click the links in the menu. If they hover over the link the browser identifies it as a valid link but if they click it nothing happens. If they right-click, Open link in new tab, it works for them...

Comment: Now it sounds like a javascript problem, but make sure the links are truly visible and throw in a high z-index for good measure.